# Are there any examples of Authenticating a User against Windows Azure Rest API without certificates

Tags: azure

According to the releases a few day ago by Scottgu, its now possible to use the windows azure management api without client certificates.

Are there any examples of doing this?

I have a Azure Cloud Service Package that I would like to let people deploy from my website. Therefore I would like to, from javascript, to authenticate the user to their Azure subscription ( some oauth against the WAAD ) and then by rest api deploy my package for them.

I dont need a concrete examples, but just some pointers on how I could do this.

I dont want users to give me their passwords offcause, therefore i need some guidance on how I can do SSO of the user against WAAD/Windows Azure management api and from there use the access token to deploy the package.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, the Service Management API documentation regarding this new authentication mechanism (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460782.aspx) is not updated. Since the new login mechanism is supported in PowerShell which is essentially a REST Wrapper over this API and is open source, one thing you could do is take a look at the source code of the Cmdlets on Github (https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-tools) to see how it is accomplished there and write something of your own (and share it here:)).

Comment: When I have a working example, i will share :) One quick question. There is no need for me to create a Application, register it with my WAAD, and let users sign in there. Would that work, would I then be able to use the token when they have signed in to do things on their azure subscription?

Comment: :). I haven't used it myself but from what I understand, this is essentially the functionality where subscription admin/co-admins can use Service Management API without using the current certificate based authentication. Key thing here is that only subscription admin/co-admins can use this functionality.

Comment: okay. will give it a go. Azure-sdk-tools are a large project :)

Comment: It seems that the powershell tools has a clientID. I am not sure where i would register my "app" to get a clientid for me. Is it an app on my WAAD that is public for others to use or is it just the LiveId oauth service

Comment: I was able to get a token by using the uri and clientId of the powershell tools. Not sure how to get a clientId for my application.

Comment: I keep getting authorization failed because of client certificate, but i am not using that. I am setting request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(AuthorizationScheme, Token); Not sure if I need to specify other headers to tell it not to use client certificate.

Comment: Until there's AAD authentication libraries that are easy to work with, this will be a little difficult. We're hoping to help get those things out soon, in the meantime a lot of the work to offer these libs as portable class libraries is just forward-looking more than useful today.